# Get json value in array based on array of foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0

I have a table `t1` which contains a column of json arrays, which correspond to the id of a foreign column `t2`:

I am trying to get a json array of all the paths associated with the ids in t1.

`t1` and `t2` look like this

```
SELECT * FROM t1

id | array
1  | [1, 2]
...


-----------------
SELECT * FROM t2

id | path
1  | path1.json
2  | path2.txt
...
```

the result should look like this

```
t1.id | paths
1     | ["path1.json", "path2.txt"]
```

With the help of a Lateral join, I have managed to get all the data I need, but each line will contain an array of only one path:

```
SELECT id, result 
    FROM t1, 
         LATERAL(
              SELECT JSON_ARRAY(path) as result
                  FROM t2 
                  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(t1.array, CAST t2.id as JSON()
---------
id | result
1  | [path1.json]
1  | [path2.txt]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the results I needed by using a `LATERAL` followed by a `GROUP BY`, however the results are awfully slow if both tables are of a reasonable size (>10k), so I will keep the question open in hopes that someone  finds a more optimized answer:

```sql
SELECT id, JSON_AGGREGATE(result)
(SELECT id, result 
    FROM t1, 
         LATERAL(
              SELECT path as result
                  FROM t2 
                  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(t1.array, CAST t2.id as JSON())
GROUP BY id
```